# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars?

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my routine which i use in a program (see below) but i keep getting the same error. What should i do to fix it?

```
def multiplos(n):
    from numpy import unique

    list=[]
    list1=[]
    list2=[]

    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
            s=17*i
            if s%10==0 and s%2==0 and s%3==0 and s%8==0 and s%19==0 and s%11==0 and s%13==0 and s%17==0:
                    list=list+[s]

    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
            m=13*i
            if m%10==0 and m%2==0 and m%3==0 and m%8==0 and m%19==0 and m%11==0 and m%13==0 and m%17==0:
                    list1=list1+[m]

    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
            t=7*i
            if t%10==0 and t%2==0 and t%3==0 and t%8==0 and t%19==0 and t%11==0 and t%17==0 and t%13==0:
                    list2=list2+[t]

    #Concatenando las tres listas
    lista_final=list+list1+list2
    #Lista sin repeticiones
    final=unique(lista_final)
    return final
```

Program:

```
n=20000

from multiplos_7_13_17 import multiplos
mult=multiplos(n)

for i in xrange(mult):
     if mult[i]%4==0 and mult[i]%6==0 and mult[i]%9==0 mult[i]%12==0 mult[i]%14==0 and mult[i]%15==0 and mult[i]%16==0 and mult[i]%17==0 and$
             print "¡Lo has encontrado!",mult[i]
     else:
             print "Este no es...D:"
```

The error `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` prints in `for i in xrange(mult):`

Comment: You either want `for num in mult:` or `for i in xrange(len(mult)):` Probably the former.

Comment: I changed the program
I want to evaluate EVERY term in the list (mult) and see which one satisfies the conditional

Comment: What is the `and$` at the end of the if statement supposed to be?

Comment: It means that for showing "print  !Lo has encontrado!",mult[i]...mult[i] needs to satisfy ALL the statements in the previous line of print

Comment: `and$` definitely isn't valid Python. You're also missing several `and` statements between predicates in your `if` statement (`mult[i]%9==0 mult[i]%12==0 mult[i]%14==0` is not valid Python, you need `and` between each predicate).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to do this:

```
for i in xrange(mult):
     if mult[i]%4==0 and mult[i]%6==0 and mult[i]%9==0 mult[i]%12==0 mult[i]%14==0 and mult[i]%15==0 and mult[i]%16==0 and mult[i]%17==0 and$
             print "¡Lo has encontrado!",mult[i]
     else:
             print "Este no es...D:"
```

Just do this:

```
for num in mult:
     if all(num % val == 0 for val in [4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17]):
         print "¡Lo has encontrado!",num
     else:
         print "Este no es...D:"
```

Your original code is broken because you're trying to pass a numpy array to xrange, but xrange only takes `int` values. What you probably meant to do was `for i in xrange(len(mult))`, but that's not the best way to iterate here, since you don't actually need the indices of the array. All you really care about is each value in the array, so using `for num in mult` is a better choice (and requires less typing, which is nice).

Additionally, I shortened your if statement by taking advantage of the fact that you're making the same comparison repeatedly. Rather than retyping `num % some_number == 0` over and over, I used `all` along with a generator expression to iterate over `[4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17]`, and only return `True` if `num % val == 0` is `True` for all of them.

**Edit:**

Here's a complete working example, with output. I also simplified and sped up the `multiplos` function, though it's still functionally equivalent to your original.

```
def multiplos(n):
    from numpy import unique

    list=[]
    list1=[]
    list2=[]

    mod_list = [2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 13, 17, 19]
    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
        s=17*i
        if all(s % val == 0 for val in mod_list):
            list=list+[s]

        m=13*i
        if all(m % val == 0 for val in mod_list):
            list1=list1+[m]

        t=7*i
        if all(t % val == 0 for val in mod_list):
            list2=list2+[t]

    #Concatenando las tres listas
    lista_final=list+list1+list2
    #Lista sin repeticiones
    final=unique(lista_final)
    return final


n = 23279256
mult = multiplos(n)

for num in mult:
     if all(num % val == 0 for val in [4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17]):
         print "Lo has encontrado!",num
     else:
         print "Este no es...D:"
```

Output:

```
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Lo has encontrado! 232792560
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
Este no es...D:
```

Comment: Notice that i already erased the n value, so num doesn't exist. In the code you wrote (thanks for the suggestion by the way) i need to change num for every value in mult (which i already did) but when i run the program nothing happens...it closes by itself

Comment: @VanesaPiedrahita That's because the `multiplos` function returns an empty list.

Comment: @VanesaPiedrahita The code will find matches if you use a huge value for `n`. `n=50000000`, for example.

Comment: You can drop 4 and 6 from the list of divisors you test against, since any number that is evenly divisible by 12 will also divide evenly by each of them.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, that's a good point. There's probably more optimizations along those lines that can be made, too, its just a bit too far outside the scope of what the OP is asking for me to try to cover them. (Though others are welcome to chime in :).